# Getting the Nokia Asha keyboard (LWUIT)

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I was wondering if there is some method of getting a reference to the Keyboard that pops up on Nokia Asha 503 full touch devices when you tap a TextArea.

I need to be able to make changes to it directly, add some buttons & possibly style it as well.

I've tried all VirtualKeyboard methods of LWUIT, as well as TextEditorProvider from TextArea but these don't work at all, just return null or don't give the intended functionality.
It makes me think that Asha doesn't support making changes to the keyboard

ALSO if anyone knows how to override the keyboard events please include that!

Thanks!

Fenix

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of wasted time, I found the problem today, which is that by default ASHA SDK has an option that forces use of their text editor over any LWUIT one until you disable that option. VERY annoying and wasted me a whole day! haha.

For anyone else having this keyboard issue, try "TextArea.setTextEditorEnabled(false)"
then try binding your VirtualKeyboard. You should have no problems.

Fenix